# iOS5: how show/hide a drawn thing in CGContext

Tags: ipad, ios5, cgcontext

I work with Xcode 4.3 for a iPad iOS 5 project.
I am performing some CG drawing operations into a CGContext in a UIView.

For example I draw a circle and move it (in response to user actions) in several positions of the UIView.

Ad some point I want to hide/remove/clear/delete this circle.

What is the best way to do this? Redraw the circle with line width = 0? Or with alpha = 0? Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redraw the view without the circle and setNeedsDisplay.